# Martin Gardner - Crazy Cut

Tags: geometry, dissection

You are to make one cut (or draw one line) – of course it needn’t be straight – that will divide the figure into two identical parts.

[Source](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/observations/2010/05/22/three-puzzles-from-martin-gardner-1914-2010/)

[image: Crazy Cut]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is this a trick question?  Here is my answer.

> [image: Crazy Cut]

Comment: Nice job! Hopefully you didn't look on Google unless you were utterly stumped, but it's all fun anyways.

Comment: No Google, just counting that there are 12 squares, so each figure must have area 6, and it turns out both areas have the cross shape.

Comment: Then kudos to you :)